# I get a contradiction in the theory of free abelian groups. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: group-theory, free-abelian-group

Hi: The definition I'll use is this: Let $F$ be an abelian group and $X$ a subset of $F$. Then $F$ is a free abelian group on $X$ if for every abelian group $G$ and every function $f$ from $X$ to $G$ there is a homomorphism $\phi$ from $F$ to $G$ that extends $f$.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $X$ a subset of $G$. Let $F$ be the free abelian group on $X$. Then $F=\langle X\rangle$ and so $F\subseteq G$. That is, every finite group has an infinite subgroup. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It will be easier to make myself clear working with free groups. I'll quote from Derek Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups, 2nd ed.

[image]

From this a free group is not only always free on a subset but additionally that subset generates it. If $G$ is a group and $X$ is a subset, however, indeed there will exist a free group on $X$ but I am unable to show it will be generated by $X$ based in the above quote. Which is very natural, of course. Thanks for the posts. Honestly none of the feedback, up to now,  throws light in the paradox (paradox for me, of course).

Comment: How do you conclude that $F\subseteq G$?  Even if $G$ is trivial, the free group on the identity $e$ is infinite, and not contained in $G$.  Remember, the relations from $G$ are not relations in $F$.

Comment: $X\subseteq G$. Then $\langle X \rangle \subseteq G$. But $F=\langle X\rangle$.

Comment: Nowhere does the definition say that the homomorphism $\phi : F \to G$ has to be injective, which is what you would need to conclude that $F \subseteq G$.

Comment: Forgive my clumsiness. But isn't F = <X>?

Comment: $F$ is the free group on the letters represented by $X$. I thought you were writing  that as $\langle X \rangle$.  People sometimes use that notation to represent the subgroup of $G$ generated by the elements in $X$.  Those two notions are not the same.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd say it was more typical to denote the Free group on a set $X$ by $F_X$.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) But, in any case, don't let the notation confuse the meaning.

Comment: Given any set Y there exists a frree abelian group F such that Y is a subset of F. Am I wrong?

Comment: That statement is correct.  Again, sticking to a single element $e$, the free group on $e$ is the set of words $F_e=\{\cdots, e^{-2}, e^{-1}, e^{0}, e^1, e^2, \cdots \}$ with the usual multiplication rule and you see that $e=e^1$ is a subset of $F_e$.

Comment: Well then let Y be a subset of G (see OP) and let F be the group whose existence I postulated above and the contradiction subsists. EXCUSE me. I did not realize you edited your comment.

Comment: Yes, I edited my comments to remove what I thought was a confusion in the notation.  If, by $\langle X\rangle$ you meant the $\textit {subgroup}$ of $G$ generated by the elements of $X$ then that is not the same as the free group on $X$.

Comment: You haven't been accepting any answers lately, @stf91.

Comment: Please give me time some time.

Answer (score 6):

You are using $\langle X \rangle$ to mean two different things, and conflating them:

1. You are using it to mean the free abelian group on $X$.
2. You are using it to mean the subgroup of $G$ generated by $X$.

These are not the same thing, but you assume that they are.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the OP. See under "EDIT" if you please. Honestly none of the feedback throws light in the paradox (paradox only for me, of course).

Comment: @stf91 Exactly the same problem exists: you are still using $\langle X \rangle$ to mean two entirely different things (or, if you prefer, you're using two different group operations to define it).

Comment: I'll quote myself (OP): "Let G be a finite group and X a subset of G. Let F be the free abelian group on X. Then F=⟨X⟩ and so F⊆G". I already realized this inference is entirely gratuitous. At least starting from the statements in the text I quoted in the OP.  Thanks for your kindness. PS: Always defining $\langle S \rangle$, where $S$ is a subset of some group as the intersection of all the subgroups including $S$.

Answer (score 1):

The $X$ in the free abelian group definition is a collection of formal symbols. They are assumed to have the minimum properties necessary for $\langle X\rangle$ to be an abelian group. That is what it means to be "free" in this context.

However, for any $\Xi\subseteq G$ for a finite group $G$, there are extra constraints on the *subgroup* $\langle \Xi\rangle_G$ of $G$; for instance, each element of $\langle \Xi\rangle_G $ is of finite order. Thus it is not free.

Answer (score -1):

Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and $[1]\in G$, let $X=\{[1]\}$ $F=<X>=G$, let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f([1])=1$, $f$ cannot be extended to $G$ in $g$, since we must have $g(5.[1])=5.f([1])=5$ and $g(5.[1])=g([0])=0$ since $g$ is a morphism of groups.